# Bootstrap Tabs without allowing click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 tabs to create a wizard of steps like seen in the image below.

[image]

I am trying to control this by not allowing clicking on the tabs directly but only allowing you to use the next / previous buttons.

The issue I’m having is in order to control the tabs programmatically through the button, each of those links up top needs a href value even if you do the index values; you can’t leave href empty.

```
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show') // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

How can I still control the navigation using my button but not allow for you to click on the tabs?

Comment: let me know if you need any help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

make your link

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

Not really sure why you would want to use an unclickable link at this point. But that's the solution.

Note you may just want to change the query to do this.

```
$('#myTab li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Taking a note from Martin, we can kill all events and propagation.

```
$('#myTab li a').click(function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Chris Coyer has a more detailed post on this: http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

You should look into changing the code rather than using jQuery to hack it. You could have the tabs just be regular list items and color the active list item. The prev and next buttons should lead your user to the next tabs in its own seq. you can either use the browser url or a page variable so you know where your user is currently located at in the tabbed process your manipulating.

Comment: You should use `href="javascript:void();"` or just `href="javascript:;"` since otherwise there is a _bit_ of functionality with `href="#"`

Comment: well if you rather not have any functionality, we could do return false;

Comment: I tried adding  $('[name=wizardTabs] li a').click(function(e){ return false;}); and it still lets me click on the links.

Comment: My goal here is to use the bootstrap Tabs feature with a forward and previous button without being able to click on the tabs them self.

Comment: go to your browser and enter the console,  $('[name=wizardTabs] li a') and type that in. if it returns[] you have an issue with your jquery selector.

Comment: is there anywhere i can see the website, i can help better seeing some more of the code or just the page itself